# Node won't log the contents of a JSON Object, regardless of method

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm wrapping data to a Node.js WebSocket server in JSON. I'm trying to log the contents of the JSON object server side, but Regardless of the method  I try, Node just logs `object Object`

I have tried

```
console.log(message.data)
console.log(util.inspect(message.data, {showHidden: true, depth: null}));
console.log(JSON.stringify(message.data));
```

Why would Node.js log `object Object` ? is the JSON malformed?

I'm sending VERY simple JSON objects from the client. Things like

```
ws.send({'a': 0, 'b': 1});
```

Comment: does it at least log null?  if it doesn't log anything at all, chances are, it never got there.

Comment: As stated in the question, it just logs "object Object" regardless of the log method. Now, if I try to log message.data.a it logs undefined

Comment: try to send it to front end and log in the browser console. May help

Comment: so, it's logging the value ***exactly*** as it is. :p

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what was happening. the client was converting the object literal. Look at @Dr Goat 's answer below..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The client might be sending `object Object`, over the websocket, not the server being unable to parse the object. Try to stringify the object before you send it.

```
ws.send(JSON.stringify({'a': 0, 'b': 1})); //client

console.log(JSON.parse(message.data)); //server
```

Comment: GOOD CATCH! That's exactly what it was. I'll accept asap.

Comment: @NativeCoder Thanks, may I suggest using the `rubber duck` method, as it helps catch errors like this.

Comment: I'm guessing that means send the data straight back to the client when it receives a message?

Comment: @NativeCoder Not exactly, heres a link to it. https://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/

Comment: I don't understand where I wen't wrong. I tried to give as pertinent information as possible, so as to avoid useless bloat in the question. Is it not concise? (I basically just said Here's what I'm trying to do, here's what I've tried, here's what I'm getting back)

Comment: @NativeCoder You got him wrong. Just google `rubber duck debugging`, read the wiki and you'll get it.

Comment: AH, So it wasn't necisarily about the question. I see. Thank you for that @Shaharyar

Comment: @NativeCoder Now you get it :)